# import csv to sqlite3 but ignore first 11 rows

Tags: csv, sqlite

i am trying to import https://www.bjs.gov/content/data/lwenfemp.csv to an sqlite3 table. i have already downloaded the cvs using a weget command i then wrote a file build-table.sql From there i made another file to run the build-table.sql by doing sqlite3 lwenfemp.db < build-table.sql now i wish to import the data from the .csv into this table. However the problem is i the first 11 lines are random text describing the file. i need the data which is lines 12 and below. Here is the code if tried but no success.

```
.mode csv
.import lwenfemp.csv
INTO TABLE lwenfemp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 11 LINES;
```

i could not find the answer anywhere else and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could i head/tail the .csv before importing it? if so how would i go about doing that?

Comment: UPDATE: i created a python program to delete the first 11 rows and write the remaining data to a new file